# Should I vote to close questions if they are outdated?

Tags: discussion

[What does the number below the energy counter mean in Spiral Knights, and what is it for?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/what-does-the-number-below-the-energy-counter-mean-in-spiral-knights-and-what-i)
[Maximizing gameplay time in Spiral Knights](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31243/maximizing-gameplay-time-in-spiral-knights/126009#126009)

These two are just an example of an update that hit Spiral Knights today.

Basically, the update completely removed the Mist Energy functionality. Which means a bunch of spiral-knights questions on Arqade are now completely outdated.

The question is, what do I do? I've voted to close on some of them, that are relatively outdated.  But should I re-edit the questions to make them more in line with the current update? Or is changing it making it way different from the question first asked?

Comment: Is it still possible to play without this update? If so, the questions are still valid.

Comment: @retro can you please link to the changelog? I'll delete my question if that's true

Comment: oh there we go. http://forums.spiralknights.com/en/node/84730

Comment: Also related, and more recent: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/what-do-we-do-with-historic-questions-that-no-longer-make-sense

Comment: Related: [Can we stop closing questions that have become obsolete as “Too Localized”?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5282/4797) and [What should be done with out of version questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5727/4797)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as Ashley states, if the game is unplayable without being on the latest patch, then the questions should be closed. However, if you can continue playing the game without updating (Looking at you, [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)) then the questions should be left open.

You could always edit an existing answer to state that the functionality has been removed in the latest version?